# Oracle ratio to report with case?

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I'm trying to find a function/way to complete the following:

Lets say we have a salary of 3 departments (1,2,3), and i do the ratio to report and get the following:

```
1 : 50
2: 49 
3: 1 
Total of 100
```

But, i need to have a minimum barrier, I'll use >1 for this example, so the result should see that department 3 isn't above 1 and should split the 1 between the other departments, so the result be as following:

```
1:50.5
2.49.5
```

Any way/function that does this?

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: There is no specific code (yet), the basic idea is to get rid of small percentages by dividing them equally in the others, in the example i gave its out of a 100 so 1=1%. Doesn't matter for me if it will based on the percentage or the amount as long as i can work with the results of the ratio

Comment: Take a look at the RATIO_TO_REPORT analytic function. More info at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions124.htm